# How to add to array in MongoDB document with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've got a collection of spellbooks in a mongodb.  One of my API calls in `express` through `mongoose` is a PUT where the user provides the ID of the document and then a body that contains an array of spells.  I want to update the array of spells in the spellbook document with the array brought in from the client.

Here's what the document looks like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56f999342c2bdee43869c33b"
    },
    "name": "malagar22",
    "username": "zak",
    "spells": [
        "56bd4da932c3b8e88e3c113a",
        "56bd4da932c3b8e88e3c113b"
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Here's what my API call looks like:

```
app.put('/api/spellbook/:id', function (req, res) {
    Spellbook.findById(req.params.id, function(err,spellbook) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({info:'error during find spellbook',error:err});
        };
        if (spellbook) {
            _.merge(spellbook, req.body);
            spellbook.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({info:'error updating spellbook',error:err});
                };
                res.json({info:'spellbook updated successfully'});
            });
        } else {
           res.json({info:'spell not found'}); 
        }
    })
});
```

As you can see, I'm finding the spellbook that matches the ID.  Then I'm doing a lodash merge with the request body, which I imagine would match the spells array in the document with the spells array in the body, which I'll post below.  Then we update.

Here's my request:

```
{
  "spells":[
        "56bd4daa32c3b8e88e3c1148"
    ]
}
```

I'm getting the success callback, but when I check the database, the document isn't being updated.  Sorry if this is really simple.  I'm an MS SQL guy and this is my first time using Express and Mongo.

Comment: print out req.body plz. also note that you're doing BOTH res.json (err) and res.json (success) in instances of error.

Comment: Here's the request body:  { spells: [ '56bd4daa32c3b8e88e3c1148' ] }

Comment: can you print the merge result? and see what it contains?

Comment: Here's the merge result.  It seems like that's the issue, but I don't know enough about lodash to know how to fix it:  { spells: [ '56bd4daa32c3b8e88e3c1148', '56bd4da932c3b8e88e3c113b' ],
  __v: 0,
  username: 'zak',
  name: 'malagar22',
  _id: 56f999342c2bdee43869c33b }

Comment: try to _.merge(spellbook.spells, request.body.spells).  then call save on spellbook.  I think that's what you want.

Comment: why do you you just use this, 

`spellbook.spells.push(res.body.spells)` and see the result.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg this also works and probably what i'd do.

Comment: Since he wasn't much aware of lodash, i thought of this will be simpler for him.

Comment: Yep, that's totally fine by me.  And it works!  Just out of curiosity though, are either of you familiar with lodash enough to figure out how to fix it with that?  The code I had above was basically just slight modifications to a tutorial I followed, which is where the lodash came from.  It seems pretty powerful and I'd love to learn to use it, but doing the spells.push works well enough for me. I assume merge checks for duplicates though?

Comment: I think merge will merge the properties of two different objects. instead of push you can also use `_.concat(arr1,arr2)`.

Comment: Would concat allow duplicates?  That's something I'm trying to avoid.  I already wrote the logic using push to prevent duplicates, but I'm curious if that could be done with lodash.